# Interactive sheet using Datanitro

Tags: python, excel, datanitro

I'm trying to create an interactive sheet that can load some data according to a cell value. For example, if the cell "A1" changes to "estructura" the range(C2:E4) will load data3 list. Is the code below a good approach or there is a better way?

```
data1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, None], [6, 7, 8]]
data2 = [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60], [70, 80, 90]]
data3 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

static = Cell("A1").value

while True:
    if static != Cell("A1").value:
        if Cell("A1").value == "mamposteria":
            CellRange("C2:E4").clear()
            Cell("C2").table = data1
        elif Cell("A1").value == "mortero":
           CellRange("C2:E4").clear()
           Cell("C2").table = data2
        elif Cell("A1").value == "estructura":
           CellRange("C2:E4").clear()
           Cell("C2").table = data3
        static = Cell("A1").value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code works. (The while loop isn't indented properly, but I assume that's a typo.)

Here's a more efficient version of the loop:

The main difference is that you're reading in the value of A1 once per loop - this'll be faster than reading it for each comparison.

```
while True:
    new = Cell("A1").value
    if static != new:
        CellRange("C2:E4").clear()
        Cell("C2").table = {"mamposteria": data1,
                            "moretero": data2,
                            "estructura": data3}[new]
        static = new
```